# Does $CABA-ABAC=A$ imply $CB=BC$ or $AB=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in GL(2n, \Bbb R)$ be an invertible skew-symmetric matrix such that $A^2+I=0$ and $B,C\in GL(2n, \Bbb R)$ symmetric matrices which $C$ is invertible and $CA=-AC$ and $C^2=\alpha I$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$. Suppose that $A,B$ and $C$ satisfies the following relation:
$$CABA-ABAC=A,\tag{1}\label{A}$$

> Then does \eqref{A} imply $CB=BC$ or $AB=BA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&-1/2\\ -1/2&-1},\ C=\pmatrix{-1\\ &1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there counterexample in dimension 4?

Comment: @C.F.G Just replace $A$ by $A\oplus A$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$.